# Convert internal stylesheet to inline css

Tags: css

how can i convert internal stylesheet to inline css of a page without using any online source.
I have style defined as

```
<style  id="custstyle" type="text/css">
            .column{
                font-size:13px;
                font-family:arial, helvetica, verdana, sans-serif;
                font-weight:normal;
                color:rgb(221, 221, 221);
                font-size:13px;
                font-family:arial, helvetica, verdana, sans-serif;
                font-weight:normal;
                color:rgb(221, 221, 221);
            }
        </style>
```

this sets style for

```
<div id="sidebar-right" class="column">Content</div>
```

but i want to convert all internal css automatically to inline css

Comment: Interesting, first your requirement is weird, and secondly, why you have each property declared twice? Or is that a result of ctrl + v (2)?

Comment: But this is inline style? :)

Comment: please let us know the purpose

Comment: for email purpose... internal css is not applied when we try to email content on the page

Comment: This is a horrific idea except if you want to use this inside an E-Mail. (Edit: ah, you answered already)

Comment: ... but as so often, it is easily Googled and that should really always be the starting point. A search for `Convert internal stylesheet to inline css` turns up a number of results, including a Java program and an online tool.

Comment: @Mr.Alien ctrl + v(2) ;)

Comment: @Pekka웃 he will be stuck - pseudo .. <<

Comment: @Pekka웃 all google results give links to online sites to convert.... i want to convert in my code.....

Comment: Then Google for `Convert internal stylesheet to inline css <name of your preferred programming language>`. It's not that hard, you know.

Comment: @user1888781 If you are doing this for emailers than I would like to inform you that making a cross browser pure html mailer is going to be really tough, better make an image, use a table, chop the image into different pieces and draft your mailer

Comment: @ProllyGeek yeah sure...

Comment: @ProllyGeek He wants to make an emailer, jQuery is not the solution for everything

Comment: @Pekka웃 i have searched alot already...

Comment: @Mr.Alien and pure javascript ? , cause i dont understand what you mean by mailer , html compiler after all ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek nothing works in mailers.. (Edit) - I see, you don't know what are mailers, mailers are something you mail in bulk to your subscribers, or say for marketing stuff etc, with fancy banners saying 20% off, 50% off etc.. so they end up in gmail, outlook, etc, which won't support scripts...

Comment: @Mr.Alien surely i will first convert the page in inline css then forward that to mail

Comment: aha i often get such mails , but only images are disabled , i think style and script may be enabled !! Or not !! never tried , let me try though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select all the div that has the `column` class and remove class column if it is there then apply inline CSS using jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var obj = $(".column");
$(obj).each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("column");//not really necessary
    $(this).css({"font-size":"13px","font-family":"arial,helvetica, verdana, sans-serif",          
            "font-weight":"normal",
            "color":"rgb(221, 221, 221)",
            "font-weight":"normal"});
});
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kh2Cu/6/)**

Answer (score 2):

this script will get you the computed CSS , after wards , you can set attribute using jquery `.css()` , or pure js `.setAttribute("style","calculated_value");`

http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/twP6S/112/

```
 $(document).ready(function()
                  {
xx=window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('stylediv')).cssText
document.getElementById('stylediv').setAttribute("style",xx)

                  });
```

this will answer your question , but concerning mailer , i dont know , needs further investegations !!

Answer (score 1):

Can you give more specifics about what you're trying to accomplish?

You could probably do something similar to

```
$('#sidebar-right').attr('style',$(.custstyle).text().split('{')[1].replace('}',''))
```

Since the styles follow the same format but that seems like a rather silly thing to do.  Maybe if you told us what you want to achieve we could be of more help.