# Convert CSS to inline CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found this awesome CSS [code](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/qjWxXZ) and what to use it on my website. But because I have to generate a lot of buttons with PHP I need to write the CSS inline as `style="..."` for the button. My question now is, how can I convert that to inline CSS?

I already googled for an converter but sadly I didn't find anything.

Comment: do you mean how do you take the SCSS and make it real CSS? is there no way to generate classes on the buttons so you don't have to do all of that as inline styles? Would you be able to replicate the HTML in the same way? a `<span>` inside a `<a>`?

Comment: SO does not allow us to recommend software. Also, on SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: You can explore UnCSS and other _critical CSS_ tools, (P)React / VueJS and other *CSS in JS* (with server-side rendering?), [Atomic CSS](https://acss.io), [emogrifier](https://www.myintervals.com/emogrifier.php) and [CssToInlineStyles](https://github.com/tijsverkoyen/CssToInlineStyles/) ([C#](http://chrispebble.com/inlining-a-css-stylesheet-with-c/)). /!\ Neither MQ nor hover/focus and :pseudo styles in a style attribute (Atomic CSS has a solution for that by using classes). Though I'm curious what is the problem with the Pen you linked to that would **need** inline styles?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert internal stylesheet to inline css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20486897/convert-internal-stylesheet-to-inline-css)

Answer (score 3):

You could put it at the top of your file surrounded by style tags.

It would then affect just that file given the associated classes were on the elements meant to be affected.

```
<style>
//css code goes here
</style>
```

**EDIT:**

If you specifically want it to be inline and dont want to type it manually then you would either have to find or write a tool that will add run a post process on it. Writing this correctly would be a challenge but Gulp might be your friend.

Comment: That isn't what he wants to do. He specifically states "inline" and as "style="

Answer (score 3):

are you looking for something like this?

```
<button style="background: blue; color: black; font-size: 15px">Im a button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSS would look like this:

```
.button {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #00C0FF 0%, #FFCF00 49%, #FC4F4F 100%);
  position: relative;
  padding: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.button span {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #191919;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 2rem 5rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

which means the html with inline styles would be:

```
<a href="#" style="background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #00C0FF 0%, #FFCF00 49%, #FC4F4F 100%);position: relative;padding: 3px;display: inline-block;border-radius: 7px;">
    <span style='display: inline-block;background: #191919;color: white;text-transform: uppercase;padding: 2rem 5rem;border-radius: 5px;font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";font-weight: 800;font-size: 3rem;'>Button</span>
</a>
```

You'd have to switch the `background` on the `.button span` is the right #hex color but that's roughly what you'd need.

Answer (score 0):

Your can try this as you said using Jquery :

```
$("button#id_name").css('background-color','red'); //<button id="id_name" ..>
$("input[type='submit']").css("background-color','red');// <input type="submit" .../>
$("a#id_name").css("background-color','red');// <a href="#" id="id_name" ..>
```

I guess is only for one button, that the reason why i didn't call attribute class.

Comment: You can use class if you want to use it on multiple buttons $(".button_class_name")

Answer (score 0):

Use a task automation tool or any server-side programming language. We may need to implement in either way.

Declare some variables.

```
my_button = '''
border: 0px;
  background: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 23px;
  right: 28px;
'''
```

and use pattern matching to replace.

```
html = '''

<input type='button' style='$my_button'>

'''
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this if you have multiple line css:

```
$('#button-id').css({
       'property1': 'value1',
       'property2': 'value2'
});
```